# Red line on google maps Overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image: Here a picture of the problem]

This is the code that I load the map with overlapping

```
function cargar_map_restaurant(latitude, longitude, icono, name_restaurant, detalle) {


directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var scroll_false = detalle ? false : true;
var punto = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var myOptions = {
    zoom : 15,
    center : punto,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel : scroll_false
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


if (detalle === true) {
    marca = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : punto,
        icon : icono,
        map : map,
        title : name_restaurant,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marca, 'click', function() {
          infobox.open(map, this);
          if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
              this.setAnimation(null);
          } else {
              this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
          }
    });
}
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("ruta"));
```

}

When you create the overlay on the map, also created a red line in an arc around the brand.

I'm not sure I'll be doing it wrong, because this happens to me in all I do overlays.

[Here's an example of the problem of link](http://www.foodmovil.com/restaurant-burger_king_americo_vespucio/27#detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.foodmovil.com/public/css/styles.css

```
canvas
{ border:1px solid red; }
```